# Data Model tools for DB2

Tags: database, database-design, db2, data-modeling, erd

I have created a Database in DB2 and tables with relationships. I would like to create a ER diagram based on my database design in DB2. MS SQL has a facility to create ER diagrams from DB schema, but DB2 doesn't seem to have one, at least to my knowledge.

Any one know of any open source tools/facility within DB2 itself for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try [TOAD](http://toadworld.com/IBMDB2/tabid/761/Default.aspx) for DB2 (freeware and commercial versions).
Download [here](http://www.toadworld.com/Downloads/FreewareandTrials/ToadforDB2Freeware/tabid/560/Default.aspx)

Also [IBM Data Studio](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/downloads/im/data/index.html) looks promising.

Comment: Please note, to use the create ERD feature of TOAD for DB2, you have to have a licensed version. Pricing here: https://shop.software.dell.com/682/purl-toad-for-ibm-db2

Answer (score 2):

[DbVisualizer](http://www.minq.se/products/dbvis/) can visualize (and much more) just about any database, provided that the relevant foreign keys have been defined. DbVisualizer isn't open source, but there is a free edition of it (which isn't limited regarding visualization).

Answer (score 1):

You can use Visio and do a database reverse engineering. I have done it and found it to be quite neat.

[Reverse engineer an existing database into a database model](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/visio/HA101154851033.aspx)

Comment: I have used visio for this before, and yes it does a neat job. I was looking for something opensource/facility in DB2; if they had added it as a feature in subsequent releases.

Comment: I used DB2v9.1 and I don't think there was any such feature.

Comment: I use 9.1, and didn't find any such feature. I was wondering if I missed it. Interestingly, IBM's RAD seems to have a data model reengineering feature. Not been quite successful in getting it to work so far.

Comment: You will find the option in Visio

Answer (score 0):

TOAD for DB2 freeware does not have the ER diagramming feature enabled. It is available only in the commercial version. ER Studio is another (expensive) option. Try Visio 2000 Enterprise edition if you can get one. It is available on ebay for about $35. Microsoft has moved the reverse engineering option in subsequent version of Visio to the expensive enterprise architect bundles.

Answer (score 0):

Aqua Data Studio has an ER Modeling tool which will work with any RDBMS. You can create, explore, detail, and modify database schemas to create fully editable and scriptable diagrams of database relationships and objects. The link to download is www.aquafold.com