# Reverse engineer a database without primary key

Tags: db2

I need help/direction to reverse engineer a DB2 database which does not have primary key or foreign key relationship. Please advise me of some tools and steps. I am relatively new to DB.

Thank you very much for your help.

Regards

Comment: What do you mean by "reverse engineer"? What does it have to do with having primary keys or referential integrity constraints?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get DDLs, you can use db2look utility, e.g.

```
db2look -d MY_DB -a -e -x -o FileOut.txt
```

To move data between different databases, look at db2move.

Otherwise you can look at [IBM Data Studio](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/downloads/im/data/index.html) or at some tools listed in [Data Model tools for DB2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147832/data-model-tools-for-db2) (altough it's a quite old post).